# Integrating facebook in php giving invalid signed request with oAuth data

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to integrate facebook php sdk

Following is the code i have tried by reading The facebook tutorial

```
// init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('APP ID','APP SECRET');

$helper = new FacebookCanvasLoginHelper();
try {
  $session = $helper->getSession();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
   echo $ex;   
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
   echo $ex;  
}
```

However what i get when i open the app on my canvas page as

```
exception 'Facebook\FacebookSDKException' with message 'Invalid signed request, missing OAuth data.' in /home/thevowaa/public_html/v1/Facebook/FacebookSession.php:267 Stack trace: #0 /home/thevowaa/public_html/v1/Facebook/FacebookSession.php(209): Facebook\FacebookSession::parseSignedRequest('ZM_-jIn_Cm4WHMZ...', NULL) #1 /home/thevowaa/public_html/v1/Facebook/FacebookCanvasLoginHelper.php(60): Facebook\FacebookSession::newSessionFromSignedRequest('ZM_-jIn_Cm4WHMZ...') #2 /home/thevowaa/public_html/v1/index.php(35): Facebook\FacebookCanvasLoginHelper->getSession() #3 {main}
```

What kind of data am i missing because there is nothing else explained in documentation.

Comment: Is your app a canvas app?

Comment: @CBroe Yes. I have created a canvas and given the url of the webapp placed on my server

Comment: I opened a bug for this on Facebook in case you want to jump in. developers.facebook.com/bugs/722275367815777 If I get a proper answer, I'll put it right here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook doc been extremely stupid. They made it hard for devs to test.

You have to Go to `developers.facebook.com > Tools > Access Tokens > Grant permission to yourself.`

That solved the problem

Comment: But that will only work for you, what if there are other testers? And after you make it public? I think the problem is that Facebook should automatically ask for the permission inside the app. This works as a temp fix to continue developing until they fix the problem. If you have a look at the link I told you before, the answered me that it is indeed a bug and they are looking for a fix

Comment: I think it will work when we will submit the app and people will try to use the app from app center

Comment: I just tried making the app public and people are still not getting a valid signed request. I'm just letting you know so you don't count on it working after you submit it to the app center. Try subscribing to this bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/722275367815777 so we can make the Facebook Team give it more attention

Comment: I found a way for it to work for everyone. I answered your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23685616/517688

Comment: A link to the access token page: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/

Answer (score 1):

I was working with the new facebook sdk and i stumbled upon this website that explains to you how to use the login feature for the SDK. the examples use namespaces so you need at least php 5.4
[link to new Facebook SDK tutorial](http://metah.ch/blog/2014/05/facebook-sdk-4-0-0-for-php-a-working-sample-to-get-started/)

Comment: i have 5.5 and i am doing the exact thing. its not working. I can't do redirect because i am on canvas page