# Facebook : Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException' with message 'Signed request has an invalid signature.'

Tags: php, facebook

I just copied the following script from facebook 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted

I downloaded the main code using composer

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    require_once '../../Facebook/autoload.php';
    print_r($_SESSION);
    //if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) || ($_SESSION['user'] < 1) || ($_SESSION['user'] == '')){
        $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => '1444966872674589',
      'app_secret' => '54362fa0c423jdui348758ea172537fb',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
      ]);   

      $helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();
      try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
      } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
      } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
      }

      if (isset($accessToken)) {
        try {
          $response = $fb->get('/me');
          $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
          // When Graph returns an error
          echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
          exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
          // When validation fails or other local issues
          echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
          exit;
        }

        echo 'Logged in as ' . $userNode->getName();
        print_r($userNode->getName());
      } 


    //}
```

But above code throws error

> ```
>   Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException' with message 'Signed request has an invalid signature.'
> ```

I have already read this links
[Integrating facebook in php giving invalid signed request with oAuth data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566644/integrating-facebook-in-php-giving-invalid-signed-request-with-oauth-data)

and

[Integrating facebook php sdk in Facebook Canvas App giving Blank page or oauthData error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477458/integrating-facebook-php-sdk-in-facebook-canvas-app-giving-blank-page-or-oauthda/23685616#23685616)

But it didn't solve my problem

please help I can't solve the problem

Comment: Avoid posting your secret. That's essentially your password for your Facebook App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling your script from your website you can try this:

replace:

`$helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();`

with:

`$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();`

also replace:

```
if (isset($accessToken)) {
    try {
      $response = $fb->get('/me');
      $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      // When Graph returns an error
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }

    echo 'Logged in as ' . $userNode->getName();
    print_r($userNode->getName());
  }
```

with:

```
$permissions = 'list of facebook permissions';///optional

if (isset($accessToken)) {
    try {
      $response = $fb->get('/me');
      $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      // When Graph returns an error
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }

    echo 'Logged in as ' . $userNode->getName();
    print_r($userNode->getName());
  }else{
       $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('url-of-calling-script.php', $permissions);
       echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>";
  }
```

Comment: I dont want to redirect, this is for canvas page, My app is already blocked for redirecting user, That's why I am trying canvashelper

Comment: Check this out [Facebook Code Exapmles](https://github.com/sohaibilyas/facebook-php-sdk-v5/)  there are some really good code examples here.

Comment: Thank you very much bro I will try it

Comment: I tried the code https://github.com/sohaibilyas/facebook-php-sdk-v5/blob/master/canvas-app-login-get-basic-info.php still the same problem. copied changed just the appid and secret

Comment: did you try this specific script:  [canvas login script](https://github.com/sohaibilyas/facebook-php-sdk-v5/blob/master/canvas-app-login-get-basic-info.php)

Comment: I created a new app and tested it, it works bro, but it doesn't work for that particular app bro

Comment: That's weird.....is the app you were trying from a long time ago?  If, so it might not work with the newer Graph API.  Were you getting the same error message on the older app?

Comment: Anyways I am thankful to you, Your posted link is very useful.